# Get Item Text with Persits Asp.Upload

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, upload

I need help with the component Persits's AspUpload. I need a simply method to get item text from form. I read the manual online http://www.aspupload.com/manual_simple.html but i think that the method presented is not good. In the manual the used method is:

```
<%
For Each Item in Upload.Form
Response.Write Item.Name & "= " & Item.Value & "<BR>"
Next
%>
```

I need to get the item.value from item. I already know the item.name. I try with this code, but it doesnt run

```
var1 = Upload.Form.Item.Name("var1").Item.Value
```

The error is:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'Upload.Form.Item'

I've found a solution but i don't like it

```
For Each Item in Upload.Form
    if Item.Name = "var1" then var1=Item.Value end if
Next
```

Do you have any more elegant solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly the documentation isn't the clearest but `Upload.Form` is a collection the [documentation says](http://www.aspupload.com/object_upload.html#Form);

> *To reference an individual form item of the collection you may use a 1-based integer index, or a string corresponding to the NAME attribute of a text item of your upload form.*

So you can access it like most collections in Classic ASP

```vb
name = Upload.Form("var1").Name
value = Upload.Form("var1").Value
```

As long as `var1` equates to the `NAME` attribute of the HTML form field element *(`INPUT`, `SELECT`, `TEXTAREA` etc)*.